# Why doesn't clang warn about implicit conversion from double to int, but do it when from long to int?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, gcc-warning

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  const long l = 4294967296;
  int i = l;
  return i; //just to silence the compiler
}
```

the compiler warns about implicit conversion (using -Wall and -std=c++14) as following:

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'const long' to 'int' changes value from 4294967296 to 0 [-Wconstant-conversion]
```

which is ok. But there is no warning if the conversion is from double to int, as in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  const double d = 4294967296.0;
  int i = d;
  return i; //just to silence the compiler
}
```

Why the compiler reacts differently in these situations?

Note 1: clang version is 3.6.2-svn240577-1~exp1

Note 2: I've tested it with many others versions of gcc, clang and icc thanks to Compiler Explorer (gcc.godbolt.org). So all tested versions of gcc (with exception of 5.x) and icc threw the warning. No clang version did it.

Comment: gcc 6.1.1 issues a warning on the double-to-int conversion.

Comment: That might be because the number you chose wouldn't truncate its decimal places

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: Assuming 32-bit `int`, the value `4294967296.0` (exactly 2**32) is well outside the range of `int`.  The conversion has undefined behavior. (I get `4196368` and no warning with clang++, `2147483647` and a warning with g++.) I'd say it's a bug in clang++.

Comment: I don't know why this is being downvoted.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah no, even if I use a literal with many decimal places, the result will be the same.

Comment: You can get a warning if you compile with `-Wconversion`, but the warning occurs even for non-problematic values, for example `const double d = 1.0; int i = d;`

Comment: @KeithThompson neither me

Comment: @KeithThompson which is not so cool. I will try in a updated version of clang++

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: The code in the question uses the same value for the `long` and `double` variables. If the conversion from `long` to `int` loses information, then so does the conversion from `double` to `int`. It is, after all, the same value.

Comment: Try running the code with ASAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by reading this great article named "What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior", specially part #3/3, at [LLVM Project Blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html), written by Chris Lattner - the main author of LLVM - I could  understand better the **Clang's Approach to Handling Undefined Behavior**.

So, in order to guarantee your strong appeal for optimization and time economy -  "ultimate performance" -

> Keep in mind though that the compiler is limited by not having dynamic
>   information and by being limited to what it can without burning lots
>   of compile time.

Clang doesn't run **all** related undefined behavior checks by default,

> Clang generates warnings for many classes of undefined behavior
>   (including dereference of null, oversized shifts, etc) that are
>   obvious in the code to catch some common mistakes.

instead of this, Clang and LLVM provides tools like **Clang Static Analyzer**, **Klee project**, and the `-fcatch-undefined-behavior` (now [UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) - **UBSan** - ) to avoid these possible bugs.

By running **UBSan** in the presented code, `clang++` with the following argument `-fsanitize=undefined` the bug will be catched as following:

`runtime error: value 4.29497e+09 is outside the range of representable values of type 'int'`

Answer (score 5):

The conversion from `double` to an integer type changes the value "by design" (think to `3.141592654` converted to an `int`).

The conversion from `long int` to `int` instead may or work or may be undefined behavior depending on the platform and on the value (the only guarantee is that an `int` is not bigger than a `long int`, but they may be the same size).

In other words the problems in the conversions between integer types are incidental artifacts of the implementation, not by-design decisions. Warning about them is better especially if it can be detected **at compile time** that something doesn't work because of those limitations.

Note also that even conversion from `double` to `int` is legal and well defined (if done within boundaries) and an implementation is not **required** to warn about it even when the loss of precision can be seen at compile time. Compilers that warn too much even when the use could be meaningful can be a problem (you just disable warnings or even worse get the habit of accepting a non-clean build as normal).

These implicit conversion rules may add up with other C++ wrinkles getting to truly odd-looking and hard to justify behaviors like:

```
std::string s;
s = 3.141592654; // No warnings, no errors (last time I checked)
```

Don't try to use too much logic with C++. Reading specs works better.

Comment: Why not? The specifications also follow the logic. In your example, if you substitute 3.141592654 by 4294967296.0 or another 127+ number  (depends on platform) do you will get a warning, because it will cause a overflow, string is actually a value type char, so make sense.

Comment: I could accept your answer as definitive, but when using a literal rather then a const variable clang throws a warning, e.g., `int i = 4294967296.0;` will cause the following warning: `warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 4294967296 to 2147483647 [-Wliteral-conversion]`.

Comment: @ViniciusSa: this is because `clang` thinks this could have been unintentional and, with that specific value, is indeed undefined behavior with 32-bit signed integers you are using (the standard says "...conversion truncates; that is the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type ...")

Comment: Well I know that the behavior is undefined by the way **I read the standard** before posting on Stack Overflow. So in other words the question is that `clang` warns about `Wliteral-conversion` but not on `Wconstant-conversion`.

Comment: I said **constant** which means that the compiler knows your value, i.e, it can be detected **at compile time**.