# Why can I initialize a string with an int?

Tags: c++

Recently a developer at my company committed some code that looked something like this:

```
char buf[50];
string str;
str = sprintf(buf, "%s", "test");
//proceeds to use str
```

The thing is, it slipped through CI because the compiler raised no warnings despite `-Wall` and `-Werror` being set.

Shouldn't this be an obvious type mismatch? You can't assign an integer to an `std::string` type without `std::to_string`...

I took a look at the list of string [assignments](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) but I can't tell which one is being triggered in this case? Is it using one of these?

```
c-string (2) string& operator= (const char* s);
character (3) string& operator= (char c);
```

I'm guessing the latter, but that still seems like a compiler fail since sprintf clearly returns `int` not `char`.

Is there a warning we could have enabled that could have saved us in this case not covered by `-Wall`?

Edit:

A related thread I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39285668/2516916

Comment: Generates a warning for me.  Is `-Wimplicit-int-conversion` included in `-Wall`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter which platform I choose. I've tried 32-bit, 64-bit, GCC, and clang, nothing generates a warning: https://repl.it/repls/DefinitiveVengefulBrowser

Comment: @Eljay which compiler version are you using? GCC 7 doesn't seem to have `-Wimplicit-int-conversion`

Comment: I use a heavily modified and instrumented version of clang.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but this code does not **initialize** `str` with an `int`. It **assigns** an `int` to `str` which has already been initialized. It was initialized when it was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some tests and here is all my results. Compiling this program:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string str;
    str = 1000;

    cout << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

With the command:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
```

you get the following warning:

```
teste.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
teste.cpp:10:11: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
str = 1000;
```

if instead of 1000 you use a number from 0 to 255 then you do not get a warning. Apparently if the number is within the range of a char the compiler is trying to transform that number into a char and the string type accepts that.

But now if you do this:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int number(){
     return 100;
}

int main ()
{
    int a = 100;
    string str;
    str = a;

    cout << str << "\n";

    str = number();
    cout << str << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

You do not get any warning and as output you get:

```
d
d
```

If instead of 100 you use 10000 in my case i got only two blank lines as result.
So after that analysis i believe that what is happening is that even if what the variable `str`  is trying to receive is a `int` The compiler is trying to make your life easier by converting everything to you, but unfortunatly in this case it made the exact opposite.

After some  research here [cpp-flags](https://caiorss.github.io/C-Cpp-Notes/compiler-flags-options.html) i finally found a combination that would have saved you:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -Wconversion -Werror
```

with `-Wconversion` you turn those implicit conversions made by the compiler into warnings and with `-Werror` you turn every warning into an error.

and then in the program above you would get:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:13:11: error: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [- 
Werror=conversion]
   str = a;
       ^
test.cpp:17:17: error: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [- 
Werror=conversion]
   str = number();
```

Comment: I've confirmed `-Wconversion` would have saved me in this case. I'm changing accepted answer to yours since I think your answer more closely answers my question.

Comment: `str = 1000;` does not use a constructor. It is an **assignment**, and it uses the assignment operator that takes a `char`. Since `char` is an arithmetic type, any numeric value can be converted to `char`. Yes, if you set your compiler to a non-conforming mode with something like "treat all warnings as errors" you get errors on valid code.

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the detail about the constructor because you are 100% correct sorry for that mistake. About turning the warnings into errors i suggested that just because he asked if a set of flags could have saved him and as i did not find a way to stop the compiler from doing that conversion the only way i found it to "block" compilation in that case was to make it see the warning of implicit conversion as an error if there is a better way of doing so please let me know !

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `snprintf` is an `int` which can be implicitely casted to a `char` therefore `str = sprintf(buf, "%s", "test");` calls the `character (3) string& operator= (char c);` assignement operator.

The usual way of preventing that is to add the `explicit` keyword, but in your case since `std::string` is in the library you can't really do anything.

One way of detecting that is using [UBSAN](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) which has an option for implicit casts.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That seems like an evil thing for a compiler to do... char -> int I understand, but int is way bigger than char and information might be destroyed if you implicitly cast the other direction!

Comment: Unfortunately this is the case :( This qualifies as an implicit cast and is called a Numeric Conversion (see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)).

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. What you're seeing here is an implicit conversion.

Comment: @Gillespie -- `char` is an arithmetic type, and arithmetic types are all inter-convertible. If implicitly converting an `int` to a `char` wasn't allowed, `char ch = 0;` would be illegal; you'd have to use a cast. Yes, that can be confusing if you haven't seen it before. No, it shouldn't be banned, although there is disagreement on this.

Comment: @PeteBecker - the compiler should recognize the difference between `char ch = 0` and `char ch = integerReturnValue()`. The compiler knows that `0` can be safely cast as char. It has no idea if it will be able to safely cast the return value of a function. Just my opinion though, obviously the compiler folks disagree.

Comment: @Gillespie -- yes, it's possible to write subtle rules that allow some conversions and not others based on the value involved. In fact, if I remember correctly, that's part of the rules for the "new" initialization syntax: `char ch{0}` is okay, but `char ch{65535};` is not (unless 65535 can fit in a `char`).

Comment: @Gillespie -- on a separate note, "The compiler knows that `0` can be safely cast as char" -- in that code, it would be an **implicit conversion**, not a cast. `char ch = char(0);` is a cast.

Comment: Yes you can use `-Wc++11-narrowing` if you wanna detect wrong initilization