# Standard regarding to Implicit conversion from double to int in an assignment

Tags: c++, standards, implicit-conversion

Here's an implicit conversion from `double` to `int`.

```
{
  const double d = 4294967296.0;
  int i = d; // no warning from compiler clang(1205.0.22.11)
  ...
}
```

Many other questions related to this such as [Why doesn't clang warn about implicit conversion from double to int, but do it when from long to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282602/why-doesnt-clang-warn-about-implicit-conversion-from-double-to-int-but-do-it-w) says that
following standard is applied for this.

> 4.9 Floating-integral conversions.
>
> 1. A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type. [ Note: If the destination type is bool, see 4.12. — end note ]

But I think `d` is an lvalue not a prvalue in the `int i = d;`.
Which standard is applied in this case so that the compiler doesn't generate any warnings?

Comment: I'd guess that the value of d becomes an independent value which is indeed a prvalue once you put it on the RHS of an assignment statement. The variable d is still an lvalue which you can use later on, but the value you assign is seen as a prvalue in that one assignment statement. But I could be wrong. I'm not a language lawyer.

Comment: GCC decently gives you one: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/647qWxKzo

Comment: "Which standard is applied in this case so that the compiler doesn't generate any warnings?" - not that the standard governs only _ diagnosable errors_ (ill-formed, etc), whereas warnings are entirely up to the implementers to decide upon. UB, for example, is ill-formed NDR (no diagnostic _required_).

Comment: @dfrib: Both parts of that statement are almost true: the standard talks about diagnostics but doesn’t require that they halt/prevent compilation, so warnings are a sufficient response, and UB and IFNDR differ in that the first is a dynamic event and the latter is a static property of the program.

Comment: @DavisHerring I see, thanks!